# how to use the wxformbuilder genetated c++ file in my vs2010 project

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I just learn wxwidget programing. I googled and only find some material about how to use the XRC fiel from wxformbuilder for vc++ 2010 projcet.  But seem the newest wxbuilder no longer provide xrc file export.

Can anyone have some experience to use the UI generated from wxFormBuilder i vs2010 c++ project?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to wx too. AFAIK the wxFormBuilder can generate the cpp/h file directly which means you don`t have to use the xrc file in your VS2010 (because the UI is also based on cpp/h).
just press <kbd>F8</kbd>,and find the generated code.